# How to consume xml from WCF in biztalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-mapper

My `WCF service` gives message in XML format and I want to parse that XML to `map` it into the `destination schema`.

WCF exposed method (let' say GetXml()) which gives collection of records (let's say Name, Phone records) in XML format. I want to further map that XML records to map to destination schema.

Please guide me as I am new to biztalk.

Comment: What does GetXml return?  A string with Xml content, a SOAP wrapped Xml Document or a plain Xml stream?

Comment: GetXml returns XML content

Comment: Yes, but exactly how will drive which binding works best.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get you

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a servicereference to consume wcf service using addServiceReference option. That will give you required schemas and binding to consume wcf service.

Comment: Hi Vikas, GetXml returns only XML content (in string format) therefore it will not import the schemas.

Comment: in that case, you would need to create schema for xml received in service response and in WCF send adapter configuration on Messages tab, select the Inbound BizTalk Message Body path using xpath. I have not tried this but should work. follow the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226478.aspx